# Combine SELECT from TABLE with all_tab_columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to combine below into a single statement -

1. Look for the existence of a column (or list of columns) in `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`.
2. If a column exists, it should be included in the SELECT column list.
3. Execute the constructed `SELECT` statement and return the result.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.TEST 
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY, 
    name varchar(20), 
    address varchar(20)
);
```

The query below only outputs the columns of interest, but does not also contain the column value.

```
SELECT c.* FROM 
    (SELECT column_name FROM all_tab_columns where 
        owner = 'SCHEMA' AND table_name = 'TEST' and column_name IN ('ID', 'NAME')) c
```

** Update **

The requirement is to get the name of the column(s) as input and return the values for each column. There is a possibility that the column name in the table does not match due to a typo or dropped before the request was made. The simplest approach is to use the SELECT statement with all columns. If the query fails because the column does not exist, remove the column from the list and re-execute the SELECT statement. The complexity of the logic increases if the stored procedure/function loops to check for an error and remove the column.

Another solution is to check the input column against the all_tab_columns table and create a SELECT query with the columns present. I had written the statement as below -

```
DECLARE 
    colname varchar2(4000); 
BEGIN
    SELECT listagg(column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name) INTO colname FROM all_tab_columns
        where owner = 'SCHEMA' AND table_name = 'TEST' and column_name IN ('ID', 'NAME', 'ADD') ;
    IF colname IS NOT NULL THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || colname || 'FROM SCHEMA.TEST WHERE ID =  1';
    END IF;
END;
```

At first glance, there are three problems with the above solution -

1. How many input columns it can accumulate at most.
2. How to use it with JDBC, the result set will always be empty. This is due to EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.
3. I am not sure how to use PK into the solution. The type of PK can be any type supported in the database.

Comment: This cannot be a single statement, because it requires dynamic SQL: result set structure cannot depend on data. Please describe what do you want to achieve and, as long as you ask more or less the same question for the third time, why you do not build proper sql with existing columns at the application side.

Comment: That should be a procedure with an out sys_refcursor parameter, using dynamic SQL. RTM on dynamic SQL and sys_refcursor. Still: better try to avoid as much as possible using dynamic SQL because it leads to runtime errors much more frequently than non-dynamic SQL and is quite difficult to debug. I think a change in database design may help you use less dynamic SQL. Generally I use dynamic SQL for setting an index unusable or rebuilding an index or creating a partition/subpartition and quite seldom the way you desire here

Comment: I agree that this is a weird requirement. Say you select all `ID` values from your database, which over all your tables and all their rows gives you a billion numbers that happen to be the IDs in some tables, then what? Please describe what you want to use this data for. It sounds like there should be a better approach to the underlying problem you want to solve. Or is this just for practise? Do you want to learn how to use dynamic SQL?

Comment: I have updated the requirements and a possible solution from my side. I need your expertise on this.

Comment: Business requirement is still not clear. As per example in previous comment: what is the business value of, for example, ID column selected from arbitrary table? Or reversed: what is the purpose to select non-existent column from a given table? Where did this column come from? Why do you expect it to contain some meaningful value if it would be added to the model later? It seems to be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 4):

You may use [Polymorphic Table Function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-optimization-and-tuning.html#GUID-A496E727-7A54-4F6E-9E8E-82DF7558063E) for this task.

However, the requirement is not clear, because you may specify the required columns when you build a SQL query: your application should be able either to specify existing columns upfront or handle absent columns in the result. In both cases this logic may be translated into the query composition task.

```
create or replace package pkg_projection as
  function describe(tab in out dbms_tf.table_t, cols varchar2 default null)
    return dbms_tf.describe_t
  ;
end pkg_projection;
/
```

```
create or replace package body pkg_projection as
  function describe(tab in out dbms_tf.table_t, cols varchar2 default null)
    return dbms_tf.describe_t
  as
  begin

    if cols is null then
      return null;
    end if;

    for i in 1..tab.column.count() loop
      /*Mark columns to be propagated*/
      tab.column(i).pass_through := ',' || upper(cols) || ',' like '%,' || trim(both '"' from upper(tab.column(i).description.name)) || ',%';
    end loop;

    return null;
  end;
end pkg_projection;
/
```

```
create or replace function f_projection(tab table, cols varchar2 default null)
return table pipelined
row polymorphic using pkg_projection;
/
```

Given this sample data:

```
create table t(
  id,val1,val2
)
  as
select level, -level, lpad(level, 3, '0')
from dual
connect by level < 4
```

it returns below results:

```
select *
from f_projection(t, 'ID,VAL')

 ID
 --
 1 
 2 
 3
```

```
select *
from f_projection(t, 'ID,VAL2')

 ID | VAL2
 ---|-----
 1  | 001
 2  | 002
 3  | 003
```

```
select *
from f_projection(t, null)

 ID | VAL1 | VAL2
 ---|------|----
 1  | -1   | 001
 2  | -2   | 002
 3  | -3   | 003
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hy0vaJFR)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in pure SQL.

You can use PL/SQL and dynamically build the SQL and a cursor:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_schema        VARCHAR2(30) := USER;
  v_table         VARCHAR2(30) := 'TEST';
  v_columns       identifier_list := identifier_list('ID', 'NAME');
  v_found_columns identifier_list;
  v_sql           CLOB;
  v_cursor        INTEGER;
  v_dummy         NUMBER;
  v_value         VARCHAR2(4000);
  v_row           PLS_INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT column_name
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_found_columns
  FROM   all_tab_columns
  WHERE  owner       = v_schema
  AND    table_name  = v_table
  AND    column_name MEMBER OF v_columns;

  IF v_found_columns IS EMPTY THEN
    RETURN;
  END IF;
  v_sql := EMPTY_CLOB() || 'SELECT "' || v_found_columns(1) || '"';
  FOR i IN 2 .. v_found_columns.COUNT LOOP
    v_sql := v_sql || ', "' || v_found_columns(i) || '"';
  END LOOP;
  v_sql := v_sql || ' FROM "' || v_schema || '"."' || v_table || '"';

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);

  v_cursor := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
  DBMS_SQL.PARSE(v_cursor, v_sql, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);

  FOR i IN 1 .. v_found_columns.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(v_cursor, i, v_value, 4000);
  END LOOP;
  v_dummy  := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(v_cursor);

  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(v_cursor) <= 0;
    v_row := v_row + 1;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Row ' || v_row);
    FOR i IN 1 .. v_found_columns.COUNT LOOP
      DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(v_cursor, i, v_value);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  ' || RPAD(v_found_columns(i), 30, ' ') || ' = ' || v_value);
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(v_cursor);
END;
/
```

Which uses the type:

```
CREATE TYPE identifier_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
```

Then if you have the table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(id, name) AS
SELECT 1, 'abc' FROM DUAL;
```

Then the output is:

> ```
> SELECT "ID", "NAME" FROM "FIDDLE_KLYCWRFYONMLIIJLPZYP"."TEST"
> Row 1
>   ID                             = 1
>   NAME                           = abc
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/k2-D7L-h)